# immersion from mobius band to $\mathbb{R^3}$

Tags: manifolds, mobius-band

> find  an immersion from mobius strip to $\mathbb{R^3}$ .

One way to represent the Möbius strip embedded in $\mathbb{R^3}$ is by the parametrization.
$$
\begin{array}{l}
x(u, v)=\left(1+\frac{v}{2} \cos \frac{u}{2}\right) \cos u \\
y(u, v)=\left(1+\frac{v}{2} \cos \frac{u}{2}\right) \sin u \\
z(u, v)=\frac{v}{2} \sin \frac{u}{2}
\end{array}
$$
for $0 \leq u<2 \pi$ and $-1 \leq v \leq 1$. so it's enough that we show above function is smooth . is this true ?

Comment: Yes, it's smooth. You should also verify that the tangent maps are injective.

Comment: Also, note that it is not an immersion *from* the Mobius strip. The domain is just $[0,2\pi) \times [-1,1]$. What is true is that its **image** is an immersed Mobius strip!

Comment: @Berci . how we can show tangent maps are injective ?

Comment: @amirbahadory Fix $u$ and $v$, compute the differential $\mathrm{d}f(u,v) : \mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}^3$ and show this linear map is injective. (where $f = (x,y,z)$ of course)